# Using matlab to read h5 file and display the data in video format

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, video-capture, hdf5

I am trying to read the data from h5 file,display it in video format and also store it in video format(.avi,mp4 etc.)

This is the properties of data displayed using: `h5disp(filename,datasetname)`

```
>  Group '/' 
>         Dataset 'sequence' 
>             Size:  1x36x36x193
>             MaxSize:  InfxInfxInfxInf
>             Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
>             ChunkSize:  1x9x9x49
>             Filters:  fletcher32, deflate(4)
```

Than I used : `data = h5read(filename,datasetname)` to read the data and also displayed it on the window.It is showing a proper matrix of data.

Than I used :

```
load cellsequence
implay(data);
```

It is showing error: Invalid video format:The 3rd dimension of file should be 1 or 3 [Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5yv4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the dimensions are incorrect. If you do

```
data1 = permute(data, [2 3 1 4]); implay(data1)
```

It should work.